# The question of the second law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, entropy, atmospheric-science

I am asking question which definitely will be considered as duplicated but **I want to ask it more explicitly to prevent empty speech.**

Suppose we have "closed" system which is consists of alone planet and its gas atmosphere. Planet gravitation sorts gas particles, cold are near the ground hot are on top. So $T$ distribution is not uniform, so $H$ is not maximum. So *axiom* (as it does not have any formal proof) known in physics as "second law of thermodynamics" is violated.

I want you to explain me what I am missing here.
At the same time, the conditions of common sense, I consider:

1. Do not drag by the ears additional concepts that no one knew when this axiom was formulated in 19th centery.
2. Use any valid math (of 19th century), but gravity must be taken into account.
3. The more complex proof you involve, the more holes there can be as in a complex program, which will be found anyway.

**UPDATE**

1. I asking again not to drag in unnecessary entities. There is no sun, there is just a huge cobblestone in space of mass M and gas pressed to its surface by attraction, while all this is in a mirror thermos, or in other words, we ignore the infrared radiation. ***In short, we are talking about the simplest model that can only be imagined and which people in the 19th century should have imagined.***
2. 2 second law of thermodynamics: H is not decreasing during time and its is going to be maximum in closed (in terms of energy pass) system. It is violated because if we set (in our simple computer model) T to be uniformly distributed, some time pass it will not be uniformly distributed because of gravitation.

Comment: What is $H$? And how is the second law violated?

Comment: You have not said how the second law is violated.

Comment: @Bob D I claimed that T is not uniformly distributed and so H is not maximum and it prevents to be maximum by gravitation and that is why I think 2LT is violated.

Comment: You still haven’t said what H is

Comment: Your system is completely undefined. Until you say explicitly what the state variables of your system are, its entropy is undefined. Please remember that entropy is a quantity that depends on the scale and level of description, see for instance the simple discussion and examples given by H. Grad: [*The many faces of entropy*](https://doi.org/10.1002)./cpa.3160140312). If you consider your system as made of particles with well-defined forces and initial and bounday conditions, it doesn't even have an entropy.

Comment: Also, a non-uniform temperature does not mean that entropy has not reached its maximum in equilibrium. In fact, for gravitational systems (which are non-extensive) non-uniformity of temperature can be a necessary condition for entropy maximum. See for example Thirring: [*Systems with negative specific heat*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01403177) and other works by Thirring, and Baryshev & Raikov: [*On the entropy of self-gravitating systems*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01004224).

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my link: Grad: [*The many faces of entropy*](https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160140312).

Answer (score 14):

Your mistake is in assuming that the system you describe will not come to thermal equilibrium at a uniform temperature $T$.

I imagine that your intuition is driven by the behavior of the Earth's atmosphere, which is certainly not in a state of global thermal equilibrium.  However, this non-equilibrium behavior is due to the fact that the Earth isn't an isolated system.  Energy pours in from the sun, heating both the atmosphere and the surface.  The uneven heating causes sustained temperature differences which are the ultimate drivers of nearly all of our atmospheric dynamics.

If you want to imagine what a planet and atmosphere at equilibrium would be like, then you should think about a lifeless rock in the interstellar void with no appreciable sources of internal heat such as radioactive decay (which is constantly pouring heat into the center of the Earth).  The planet and atmosphere should also be enclosed in a reflective, thermally insulating shell to prevent any radiation from entering or leaving.

After a sufficient amount of time, such a system would reach equilibrium with a uniform temperature, but it wouldn't look anything like the Earth.

Comment: "However, this non-equilibrium behavior is due to the fact that the Earth isn't a closed system. Energy pours in from the sun, heating both the atmosphere and the surface"  A closed system allows energy transfer (heat, work) but no mass transfer. With the exception of an occasional meteorite, the earth is essentially a closed system because virtually no mass is exchanged between the earth and rest of universe. I think the OP (and you) mean an isolated system.

Comment: @BobD Yes, indeed you’re right.

Comment: @J.Murray You have a very bad opinion of me. My intuition had nothing to do with the earth. I just meant the most simple mathematical model with a lifeless piece of stone in space with an atmosphere. But unfortunately from what you have written, it is completely unclear to me why the distribution of the gas temperature along the height should be uniform. You just said it without proof and that's it.

Comment: @MaratZakirov Your intuition *does* have to do with the Earth, because you think that gravity sorts gas by temperature. On Earth, hot air rises not because it is hot, but because it is less dense.  Gravity sorts gas by *density*, not by temperature.  In an isothermal atmosphere, the temperature is uniform and gravity simply causes the density of the air to vary [exponentially with altitude](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/lectures/node55.html).

Comment: If you have uneven heating, then is reaching thermal equilibrium impossible? Could be nice if you could share thoughts on this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/585055/what-is-the-nature-of-steady-state-for-a-temperature-field)

Comment: I'm not sure that the final state of equilibrium would have a uniform temperature. This is a self-gravitating, non-extensive system, its thermodynamic properties are different from those of commonly encountered extensive systems...

Comment: @pglpm This is not a purely self-gravitating system.  The vast, vast majority of the mass of a planet/atmosphere system is in the solid state.  Based on my understanding of the OP's hypothetical system, the departure from "laboratory thermodynamics" (to quote the paper you reference in your comments) should be minimal.

Comment: I agree that the OP's issues boil down to some more basic misunderstanding of equilibrium thermodynamics. But still, with regard with non-uniformity of temperature I believe we are in a borderline situation, so just saying flat-out that the temperature will be uniform makes me uncomfortable. But the main point, I believe, is that the second law in its full generality says nothing about uniformity of temperature, so the OP's argument has a hole there.

Comment: @pglpm You're of course entitled to your well-reasoned reservations. My understanding is that the subtleties which arise when treating self-gravitating systems are due to the negative contribution of the gravitational binding energy and the treatment of the system as being open.  Since the latter is ruled out by assuming that the system is isolated, and the former is almost completely negligible compared to the thermal energy content of the solid planet, my conclusion is that the atmospheric subsystem will behave as a spherically-confined gas with a radially-varying chemical potential.

Comment: I understand that and in fact I tend to agree with you. My point is that the OP seems to be assuming this implication: "entropy at a maximum" $\Rightarrow$ "$T$ uniform" (in equilibrium). This implication is generally false, so even if we try to prove that $T$ is actually uniform, we aren't addressing the misunderstanding at the bottom.

Comment: Temperature gradient does exists https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate. And if we recall Maxwell's thought experiment with two gas columns, then we will get a direct contradiction with the 2law: entropy decreasing, pumping heat from a colder body to a hotter one. Also, I will be glad you to check my second question which is more explicit and correctly stated (I hope) https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/595758/what-is-the-reason-of-dt-dh-0-in-the-gas-column

Comment: @MaratZakirov As I wrote in my comment before, the lapse rate on Earth is nonzero because the Earth is not an isolated system in equilibrium. Your example question refers to an entirely different case, and the lapse rate there would be zero.

Comment: @J.Murray If you look at the Wikipedia page I mentioned, you should see "Mathematics of the adiabatic lapse rate". You see that key word ADIABATIC? So as I mentioned before, sun or external energy flow is not the case here, please read carefully.

Comment: @MaratZakirov Adiabatic does not refer to the whole atmosphere, it refers to the *individual parcels of air* which are heated at the surface and then subsequently rise.  If you read the section "Convection and adiabatic expansion," you will find a discussion of how sunlight drives convection in the atmosphere.

Comment: @J.Murray Where can I see in "Mathematics of the adiabatic lapse rate" section a word about entropy or second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: @MaratZakirov I don't know what you mean.  The *consequences* of the second law are everywhere - in particular, the words *in equilibrium* mean that the entropy of the system is maximized, subject to whatever constraints have been imposed.

Comment: @J.Murray You're constantly making the same logic error. I am asking for proofs not beliefs.

Comment: @MaratZakirov You're not asking for anything.  You're reading a Wikipedia article and then telling the physics community that we're all idiots.  In fact, you're not even reading the whole article - if you look literally one or two sections above the one you reference, you'll see explicit discussions about how all of the subsequent processes are driven by external energy sources like the sun. I've said all I intend to - if you refuse to accept that your 30 second evaluation of thermodynamics might be flawed, I have no interest in trying to help you learn.

Comment: @J.Murray, Please do not use abusive language. You've seen the math, right? How does it follow from these calculations (not your specific interpretations of certain words) that the temperature will equalize?

Answer (score 3):

I think that such an atmosphere, left to itself, is not necessarily isothermal when there are air packets moving up and down, but with enough time it will eventually become isothermal, but the timescale for this is very long. The effect of gravity is taken into account via the chemical potential, and the long-term equilibrium has higher density and higher pressure at the bottom of any air column.

*A little more detail*

Each cell of gas can exchange internal energy, volume and particles with its neighbours. In equilibrium the chemical potential and the temperature are uniform, because only then is there no net flow of energy and particle number up or down. The pressure is not uniform because the force on any given cell includes both a contribution from gravity and a contribution from the pressure of the adjacent cell.

Comment: Please be more explicit. I claimed that hot particles (with biggest/bigger kinetic energy) will be on the top atmospheric layer of that planet. I was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give an answer from a different point of view, besides the valid answers already given.

The second law of thermostatics says that if a system is in a stable equilibrium (under particular constraints), then its entropy has an absolute-maximum value (compatible with those constraints).

We note that this law says nothing about *gradients*, that is, non-uniformities. It only mentions "equilibrium".

Then how is "equilibrium" defined? Its definition depends on the specific system we're considering. A basic requirement of equilibrium is that the quantities that define the state of our system be constant in time (with respect to some reference system; note, however, that I've heard arguments even against such requirement). But equilibrium *does not generally require uniformity*. That is, in a state of equilibrium some systems may very well have gradients of density, temperature, or internal energy, as long as such gradients are constant in time.

A very simple example of this is a system made of two closed chambers, adiabatically insulated, with two substances in equilibrium at different temperature. Such a system is in equilibrium, satisfies the second law, and has non-uniform temperature. Note that there are non-trivial analogues of this kind (systems with uncoupled degrees of freedom, such as momentum and spin, for example).

So the fact that a system has some gradient in temperature, constant in time, does not a priori exclude that it is at equilibrium and that its entropy is at a maximum. For some systems, temperature non-uniformity might be impossible at equilibrium; but for other systems temperature *uniformity* might actually be impossible at equilibrium. So we *cannot* say in general "I see temperature non-uniformity, therefore the entropy can't be at a maximum".

Now I don't know whether the "earth" system at equilibrium has to have uniform temperature or maybe must have non-uniform temperature. The other answers reasonably argue that it should have uniform temperature. But the point is this: even if its equilibrium turned out to have non-uniform temperature, the second law wouldn't be violated a priori, because the second law doesn't require uniformity, that is, the absence of gradients, of any quantity.

Let me also counter the possible objection that a gradient in temperature, $\nabla T$, would imply a heat flux, $\pmb{q}$. First of all, the equation $\pmb{q} \propto - \nabla T$ is a *constitutive* equation, not a universal law. That is, it may not be valid for some materials (there maybe other microscopic phenomena, such as microscopic transport, or electromagnetic fields, that lead to a different or vanishing heat flux). Second, I can't a priori exclude a system, especially a gravitational one, with stationary, *internal* heat fluxes (I'm happy is someone can give me references about a general physical impossibility, or examples, of such a situation). Does "equilibrium" excludes such fluxes? This is a tricky question; the notion of equilibrium is not clearly delimited.

Comment: If two subsystems are not at the same temperature (so $\beta_1 > \beta_2$), then by transferring a small amount of energy  $\delta E$ from $2$ to $1$, the total entropy of the two subsystems will increase: $dS = dS_1 +dS_2 = \frac{\partial S_1}{\partial E} \delta E + \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial E}(-\delta E) = (\beta_1-\beta_2)\delta E > 0$. As a result, if there are spatial variations in the temperature, then there are other configurations with the same total energy (and identical distributions of particle number and volume) which have higher entropy. I don't see any way around this.

Comment: Take a system composed of several insulated, adiabatically separated chambers, each with some substance in equilibrium at a different temperature. Such a system is in equilibrium, satisfies the second law, and has non-uniform temperature.

The second law concerns constrained equilibria, and every equilibrium is constrained. Take an ideal gas in equilibrium in a container. Now remove the walls of the container (which were the constraints of that equilibrium). What happens? Then the previous state was not a "real" equilibrium?

Comment: Obviously my comment refers to subsystems which are in thermal contact and can exchange energy, as adjacent parcels of air in the atmosphere can.  A nonuniform temperature distribution is of course trivially possible if you consider a disconnected system comprised of pieces which are thermally isolated from one another. But that is wholly uninteresting and unrelated to the present conversation RE an isothermal atmosphere.

Comment: Let me walk that back somewhat - it's not uninteresting as a concept, but in the context of the present discussion about an isolated system where every piece is in thermal contact with its neighbors, I don't see how it's relevant regarding how to get around the standard argument that the temperature should be everywhere uniform in equilibrium.

Comment: Your comment did not mention that, and in that case I don't see how it concerns my answer, which considers any kind of general system.

Non-uniform temperature distributions are non-trivially possible. There are systems where different degrees of freedom may be uncoupled for complex reasons (say, electron spins in a metal) and that have different temperatures.

The OP statement is that since the temperature is non-uniform, the second law is violated. Such statement is generally false.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. As I wrote, I wanted to make a complementary point, making sure that the OP understands that temperature non-uniformity cannot be generally taken, a priori, as a violation of the second law.

Comment: In that case, I have no objection. +1

Comment: No problem. Actually thank you, the example with uncoupled degrees of freedom is useful to make the point that temperature non-uniformity is not a violation of the second law.

Comment: @J.Murray By the way, note that your first comment assumes extensivity of the entropy ("$dS =dS_1 + dS_2$"), which is a moot assumption for large self-gravitating systems :) But again, with this comment I don't mean that your answer is wrong. The thermostatics of gravitating systems is an extremely fascinating field :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a planet - just consider a tall column of gas in a cylinder.

The energy of a molecule is $mgh+{1 \over 2} m v^2$

You argue - correctly - that a molecule needs a lot of energy to reach the upper regions, so the mean energy of molecules at the top must be greater than that of molecules at the bottom.

But this doesn't imply an increased temperature. As an energetic molecule with high $v$  travels upwards kinetic energy is converted to potential and $v$ falls, so the velocity distribution at the top is the same as the velocity distribution at the bottom.

The proof is easy.  The Boltzmann function is $P(h,v)=P(E)\propto e^{-E/kT}$ which is
$e^{-mgh/kT-{1 \over 2kT} mv^2}$. And this factorises. $P(h,v)=P_h(h)P_v(v)=e^{-mgh/kT} e^{-{1 \over 2kT} mv^2}$. (We get the barometric equation for free.) The distribution of velocities, which depends on $T$, is the same at all heights.

Comment: The Boltzmann equation is derived based on the assumption (axiom) that T (as mean kinetic energy of partials) will be the same at each height. So basically you didn't proof anything your statement A is A because it is A. This called tautology.

Answer (score 0):

It is in no way possible for your the atmosphere to sustain a non uniform temperature distribution unless there is some external agency supplying heat to the system.

Even if your system initially starts with a non-uniform temperature distribution then too heat flow would occur between layers at different temperature. This heat flow between different layers will continue untill all the layers are in thermal equilibrium.

Now if you believe that you can have a temperature gradient by virtue of gravity then you are completely wrong. If there will be any gradient then that will be of pressure and density (at equilibrium).